# Stop Header from getting refreshed everytime a page loads

Tags: refresh

I have social network using the oxwall CMS. http://www.goplugged.com
Now, I don't want the header which contain the "GO PLUGGED" and "Homey, my profile, search for pluggers", etc.(you may log in to see it) to get refreshed everytime a page loads. That means I want it to be fixed  like in facebook and not getting refreshed everytime a page loads. I have searched a lot but couldn't find any satisfactory results. Hope I get it here.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with sessions? You can assign to it any value and keep it as a memo..

Comment: session or cookies could do that

Comment: Plus facebook does not have fixed header

Comment: Can you help me in details? I'm a newbie and do not know much regarding sessions or cookies. So, please help me. Please tell me which codes do I need to edit! The header is a div and I want two divs to stop getting refreshed everytime he page refreshes. Those are ".ow_menu_wrap" and ".ow_site_panel". I don't want these two divs to get refreshed everytime. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an Oxwall developer, here are my thoughts.

You need to edit the core oxwall core files, which sends our the headers.

BTW, what problem do you see having this?